# Unable to get required output for simple Hadoop mapreduce program

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to write this mapreduce program which has to take input from two files, one has the details of occupations and states , and the other has details of occupation and job growth percentage. I use two mappers and combine them and in my reducer try to see which jobs have growth percent more than 30. My output should ideally be the occupation followed by the list of states. I am however, only getting the occupation names and not the states. I have posted the code and the sample input files below. PLease point out what i am doing wrong. Thanks.
(Please note that the samples of the input files i have provided are just small portions of the actual files).

```
package com;

import java.io.IOException;

//import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;


public class GrowthState extends Configured implements Tool {

    //Parser for Mapper1
    public static class StateParser{

        private String State,Occupation;

        public void parse(String record){

            String str[] = record.split("\t");
            if(str[4].length() != 0)
                setOccupation(str[4]);
            else
                setOccupation("Default Occupation");

            if(str[2].length() != 0)
                setState(str[2]);
            else
                setState("Default State");

        }

        public void parse(Text record){
            parse(record.toString());
        }

        public String getState() {
            return State;
        }

        public void setState(String state) {
            State = state;
        }

        public String getOccupation() {
            return Occupation;
        }

        public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
            Occupation = occupation;
        }
    }

    //Mapper1  - Processing state.txt
    public static class GrowthMap1 extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>{
        StateParser sp = new StateParser();
        Text outkey = new Text();
        Text outvalue = new Text();
        public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            sp.parse(value);
            outkey.set(sp.getOccupation());
            outvalue.set("m1\t"+sp.getState());
            context.write(outkey,outvalue);
            //String str[] = value.toString().split("\t");
            //context.write(new Text(str[2]), new Text("m1\t"+str[4]));
        }
    }

    public static class ProjParser{
        private String Occupation,percent;

        public void parse(String record){
            String str[] = record.split("\t");
            if(str[0].length() != 0)
                setOccupation(str[0]);
            else
                setOccupation("Default Occupation");

            if(str[5].length() != 0)
                setPercent(str[5]);
            else
                setPercent("0");
        }

        public void parse(Text record){
            parse(record.toString());
        }

        public String getOccupation() {
            return Occupation;
        }

        public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
            Occupation = occupation;
        }

        public String getPercent() {
            return percent;
        }

        public void setPercent(String percent) {
            this.percent = percent;
        }
    }

    //Mapper2 - processing projection.txt
    public static class GrowthMap2 extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text> {
        ProjParser pp = new ProjParser();
        Text outkey = new Text();
        Text outvalue = new Text();
        public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            pp.parse(value);
            outkey.set(pp.getOccupation());
            outvalue.set("m2\t"+pp.getPercent());
            context.write(outkey, outvalue);
            //String str[] = value.toString().split("\t");
            //context.write(new Text(str[0]), new Text("m2\t"+str[5]));
        }
    }

    //Reducer
    public static class GrowthReduce extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>{
        Text outvalue = new Text();
        public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<Text> value,Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            float cent = 0;
            String state = "";
            for(Text values : value){
                String[] str = values.toString().split("\t");
                if(str[0].equals("m1")){
                        state = state + " " + str[1];
                }else if(str[0].equals("m2")){
                    try{
                        cent = Float.parseFloat(str[1]);
                    }catch(Exception nf){
                        cent = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(cent>=30){
                outvalue.set(state);
                context.write(key,outvalue );
            }
        }
    }

    //Driver

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Job job = new Job(getConf(), "States of Growth");

        job.setJarByClass(GrowthState.class);
        job.setReducerClass(GrowthReduce.class);

        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]), TextInputFormat.class, GrowthMap1.class);
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, GrowthMap2.class);

        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[2]));

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        return job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        int exitcode = ToolRunner.run(new GrowthState(), args);
        System.exit(exitcode);
    }

}
```

Sample input file1:

```
01  AL  Alabama 00-0000 All Occupations total   "1,857,530" 0.4 1000.000    1.00    19.66   "40,890"    0.5 8.30    9.72    14.83   23.95   36.04   "17,260"    "20,220"    "30,850"    "49,810"    "74,950"        
01  AL  Alabama 11-0000 Management Occupations  major   "67,500"    1.1 36.338  0.73    51.48   "107,080"   0.6 24.54   33.09   44.98   62.09   88.43   "51,050"    "68,830"    "93,550"    "129,150"   "183,940"       
01  AL  Alabama 11-1011 Chief Executives    detailed    "1,080" 4.8 0.580   0.32    97.67   "203,150"   2.5 52.05   67.58   #   #   #   "108,270"   "140,570"   #   #   #       
01  AL  Alabama 11-1021 General and Operations Managers detailed    "26,480"    1.5 14.258  0.94    58.00   "120,640"   0.9 27.65   35.76   49.00   71.44   #   "57,510"    "74,390"    "101,930"   "148,590"   #       
01  AL  Alabama 11-1031 Legislators detailed    "1,470" 8.7 0.790   1.94    *   "21,920"    3.5 *   *   *   *   *   "16,120"    "17,000"    "18,450"    "20,670"    "32,820"    TRUE    
01  AL  Alabama 11-2011 Advertising and Promotions Managers detailed    80  16.3    0.042   0.19    44.88   "93,350"    9.5 21.59   30.28   38.92   52.22   74.07   "44,900"    "62,980"    "80,960"    "108,620"   "154,060"       
01  AL  Alabama 11-2021 Marketing Managers  detailed    610 11.5    0.329   0.24    61.28   "127,460"   7.4 31.96   37.63   53.39   73.17   #   "66,480"    "78,280"    "111,040"   "152,200"   #       
01  AL  Alabama 11-2022 Sales Managers  detailed    "2,330" 5.4 1.253   0.47    54.63   "113,620"   2.2 27.28   35.42   48.92   67.62   89.42   "56,740"    "73,660"    "101,750"   "140,640"   "186,000"       
05  AR  Arkansas    43-4161 "Human Resources Assistants, Except Payroll and Timekeeping"    detailed    "1,470" 6.6 1.265   1.26    17.25   "35,870"    1.5 11.09   13.54   17.11   20.74   23.30   "23,060"    "28,170"    "35,590"    "43,150"    "48,450"        
05  AR  Arkansas    43-4171 Receptionists and Information Clerks    detailed    "7,080" 3.3 6.109   0.84    11.26   "23,420"    0.8 8.14    9.19    10.87   13.09   14.94   "16,940"    "19,110"    "22,600"    "27,230"    "31,070"        
05  AR  Arkansas    43-4181 Reservation and Transportation Ticket Agents and Travel Clerks  detailed    590 23.6    0.510   0.50    12.61   "26,220"    6.1 8.99    9.81    10.88   14.82   20.59   "18,710"    "20,400"    "22,630"    "30,830"    "42,830"        
05  AR  Arkansas    43-4199 "Information and Record Clerks, All Other"  detailed    920 4.7 0.795   0.61    18.45   "38,370"    1.8 13.59   15.33   18.49   21.35   23.86   "28,270"    "31,880"    "38,470"    "44,410"    "49,630"        
05  AR  Arkansas    43-5011 Cargo and Freight Agents    detailed    480 16.5    0.418   0.73    *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *       
05  AR  Arkansas    43-5021 Couriers and Messengers detailed    510 12.4    0.444   0.84    11.92   "24,790"    2.1 8.73    9.91    11.26   13.49   16.03   "18,160"    "20,620"    "23,420"    "28,060"    "33,350"
```

sample input file 2:

```
Management occupations  11-0000 "8,861.5"   "9,498.0"   636.6   7.2 22.2    "2,586.7"   "$93,910"   —   —   — 
Top executives  11-1000 "2,361.5"   "2,626.8"   265.2   11.2    3.3 717.4   "$99,550"   —   —   — 
Chief executives    11-1011 330.5   347.9   17.4    5.3 17.7    87.8    "$168,140"  Bachelor's degree   5 years or more None
General and operations managers 11-1021 "1,972.7"   "2,216.8"   244.1   12.4    1.0 613.1   "$95,440"   Bachelor's degree   Less than 5 years   None
Legislators 11-1031 58.4    62.1    3.7 6.4 —   16.5    "$19,780"   Bachelor's degree   Less than 5 years   None
"Advertising, marketing, promotions, public relations, and sales managers"  11-2000 637.4   700.5   63.1    9.9 3.4 203.3   "$107,950"  —   —   — 
Advertising and promotions managers 11-2011 35.5    38.0    2.4 6.9 17.8    13.4    "$88,590"   Bachelor's degree   Less than 5 years   None
Marketing and sales managers    11-2020 539.8   592.5   52.7    9.8 2.6 168.6   "$110,340"  —   —   — 
Marketing managers  11-2021 180.5   203.4   22.9    12.7    2.6 61.7    "$119,480"  Bachelor's degree   5 years or more None
Sales managers  11-2022 359.3   389.0   29.8    8.3 2.7 106.9   "$105,260"  Bachelor's degree   Less than 5 years   None
Public relations and fundraising managers   11-2031 62.1    70.1    8.0 12.9    1.6 21.3    "$95,450"   Bachelor's degree   5 years or more None
Operations specialties managers 11-3000 "1,647.5"   "1,799.7"   152.1   9.2 3.3 459.1   "$100,720"  —   —   — 
Administrative services managers    11-3011 280.8   315.0   34.2    12.2    0.1 79.9    "$81,080"   Bachelor's degree   Less than 5 years   None
Computer and information systems managers   11-3021 332.7   383.6   50.9    15.3    3.1 97.1    "$120,950"  Bachelor's degree   5 years or more None
Financial managers  11-3031 532.1   579.2   47.1    8.9 5.1 146.9   "$109,740"  Bachelor's degree   5 years or more None
Industrial production managers  11-3051 172.7   168.6   -4.1    -2.4    6.1 31.4    "$89,190"   Bachelor's degree   5 years or more None
Purchasing managers 11-3061 71.9    73.4    1.5 2.1 0.3 17.3    "$100,170"  Bachelor's degree   5 years or more None
"Transportation, storage, and distribution managers"    11-3071 105.2   110.3   5.1 4.9 4.8 29.1    "$81,830"   High school diploma or equivalent   5 years or more None
Compensation and benefits managers  11-3111 20.7    21.4    0.6 3.1 —   6.1 "$95,250"   Bachelor's degree   5 years or more None
Human resources managers    11-3121 102.7   116.3   13.6    13.2    1.0 40.6    "$99,720"   Bachelor's degree   5 years or more None
Training and development managers   11-3131 28.6    31.8    3.2 11.2    —   10.7    "$95,400"   Bachelor's degree   5 years or more None
Other management occupations    11-9000 "4,215.0"   "4,371.0"   156.1   3.7 43.1    "1,207.0"   "$81,940"   —   —   —
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your reducer.

The faulty code is shown below. The loop below gets called for all the values of a particular key (for e.g. for "Advertising and promotions managers", it gets called twice. Once with value "Alabama" and again with value "6.9"). Problem is, you have put the `if(cent >= 30)` statement, outside the `for` loop. It should be inside, for matching the key.

```
  for(Text values : value){
        String[] str = values.toString().split("\t");
        if(str[0].equals("m1")){
                state = state + " " + str[1];
        }else if(str[0].equals("m2")){
            try{
                cent = Float.parseFloat(str[1]);
            }catch(Exception nf){
                cent = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if(cent>=30){
        outvalue.set(state);
        context.write(key,outvalue );
    }
```

Following piece of code works fine.

```
//Reducer
public static class GrowthReduce extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>{
    Text outvalue = new Text();
    HashMap<String, String> stateMap = new HashMap<String, String>();


public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<Text> value,Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    float cent = 0;

    for(Text values : value){
        String[] str = values.toString().split("\t");

        if(str[0].equals("m1")){
            stateMap.put(key.toString().toLowerCase(), str[1]);
        }
        else if(str[0].equals("m2")){
            try{
                cent = Float.parseFloat(str[1]);
                if(stateMap.containsKey(key.toString().toLowerCase()))
                {
                    if(cent>30) {
                        outvalue.set(stateMap.get(key.toString().toLowerCase()));
                        context.write(key, outvalue);
                    }
                    stateMap.remove(key.toString());
                }
            }catch(Exception nf){
                cent = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The logic is:

1. As and when you encounter a state (value "m1"), you put it in state map.
2. Next time, when you encounter percent with same key (value "m2"), you check if the state is already in the map. If yes, then you output the key/value.